# How to call JQuery CheckBox Changed Event inside a Jquery Accordion Header?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Thanks for all your valuable responses to the questions that I have asked before, those suggestions helped me a lot.
I have one more question here.
I am using a JQuery accordion control in my page,and the accordion header contains a checkbox,
Based on the checkbox selection, I need to retrieve some date from the DB.
So, I need the checkbox changed event to get fired, but The event never gets fired for some reason. I am building the checkboxes dynamically through code.

**Code:**

```
string sa= '';
sa+= '<h3><a href=#><input type=checkbox runat=server OnCheckedChanged=chkScores_CheckedChanged id=chkScorecard' + i + '>Auckland Aces</input></a></h3><div><p>';
```

after creating checkboxes like above, I am adding them to the accordion div.

If you observe, I am giving **OnCheckedChanged** event, but that event is not firing.

Any idea..Why it is happening like that. I have been trying for past 6 hours on this, but no luck.

Can you guys please tell me if I am doing anything wrong, or is there any alternate approach to this.

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

you write

`OnCheckedChanged=chkScores_CheckedChanged`

covert it to

```
OnCheckedChanged="chkScores_CheckedChanged"
```

**EDIT:**

true, this will not work because it an html input and the event **oncheckedchanged**, and this event is for **asp:CheckBox** and at runtime it will covert to input html with

```
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'checkBox1\',\'\')', 0)"
```

so, if you want, you can add **onclick** javascript function to the input and in this function call the server side,

**Example using JQuery:**

Insert input checkbox:

```
var htmlTags = '<input id="checkboxID" type="checkbox" runat="server"  onclick="CheckboxChange(this.id)" enableviewstate="true" />';
```

Add an Button to call it event:

```
<asp:Button ID="lbtnRefreshGV" runat="server" Text="" Height="0px" Width="0px" Style="visibility: hidden"  OnClick="lbtnRefreshGV_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Add javascript function

```
function CheckboxChange(id) {
        alert("In CheckboxChange");
        alert(id);
        $('#lbtnRefreshGV').trigger('click');
        alert("Out CheckboxChange");
    }
```

Comment: Its not wotking even if I give OnCheckedChanged="chkScores_CheckedChanged"